# images not showing up when running JAR

Tags: java, image, jar, embedded-resource

I've spend 5 hours already and have no idea why images are not loaded when running Jar.

Project structure:

```
Blackjack_Game
 - Source Packages
   - Images
   - blackjack
        .... classes...
```

At project properties I have src - Source Packages folder added by default. Tried to put images directly into the project's folder and removing /Images/, but still no help.

Inside the code I have:

```
dealer_url = getClass().getResource("/Images/4_of_hearts.jpg");
File img = new File(dealerCardGenerator.dealer_url.getPath());
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(img);
dealerCardGenerator.imageIcon = new ImageIcon(bufferedImage);
```

So inside NetBeans IDE everything is OK. Fully working. But after built&clean I see no images, but all actions are done.

Can you please suggest what is wrong? Getting so mad because of this ((((

Comment: A jar is a zip, so check the path in it. Especially it must be case-sensitive, and Windows is case insensitive, so it might run unpacked in the IDE.

Comment: Filenames in a JAR are case **sensitive**. `"/Images/4_of_hearts.jpg"` is a different file than e.g. `"/Images/4_of_hearts.JPG"`

Comment: As mentioned before, make sure to check for case sensitivity. Also be sure to put the files in the correct sub folder. I had this same assignment my sophomore year, and that was  a problem that I encountered.

Comment: Thank you for replies..The path of Images folder inside JAR is at root dir: so opening JAR with winrar shows 3 folders: blackjack_game, Images, META_INF.  I've also check all file names, everything seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

A jar entry is not a file. `java.io.File` can only identify a file, not a jar entry. `java.net.URL` however *can* identify a jar entry using the `jar:` scheme, *or* a file using the `file:` scheme. That's why `Class.getResource()` returns a `URL` not a `File`.

Two solutions:

- use the `URL`: `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("whatever"))`
- `ImageIO` can also use an already-opened stream, which classloader can provide:
  `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("whatever"))`

Duplicate of at least #2-4 of the questions autosuggested as related:

- [Including Images with an executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488836/including-images-with-an-executable-jar?rq=1)
- [Loading images in a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437752/loading-images-in-a-jar?rq=1)
- [Getting images from a .jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489773/getting-images-from-a-jar-file?rq=1)

Comment: So am I correct that you recommend to replace e.g. dealer_url = getClass().getResource("/Images/7_of_clubs.jpg"); with something like ImageIO.read.....I will give a try, but really don't understand why this works inside the IDE but not working from executable JAR

Comment: *"really don't understand why this works inside the IDE but not working from executable JAR"*  In the IDE, the resource **is available** as a `File`, once in a Jar, it isn't.  Or, from my 'copy/paste comment' .. Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: .. but basically, @dave_thompson_085 has completely nailed it.  Note: I'd always go for the URL over a raw `InputStream`.  Perhaps not relevant here, but some APIs require a **repositionable input stream** whereas the `getResourceAsStream(..)` method will often return a stream that is not repositionable.  It can be fixed by wrapping the input stream in a buffered input stream, but by using an URL directly, we don't need to worry about it.  Another factor is that (for example) Java's image loading ability will cache a resource from an URL, but cannot do that for a raw stream.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for clarifying the problem. I've realized why some functions were not working.

So the solution is to replace URL with ImageIcon:

```
ImageIcon i2 = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("whatever"));
```

and then just set icon as label icon:

```
jLabel1.setIcon(i2);
```

In this way JAR works. Previously, all methods after this icon set operation were not working, as the program was actually stopped, now everything works fine.